# Need help to figure out a batch file

Tags: batch-file

How do I determine the value of variable ecg in the batch file given below ?

```
for /f "Tokens=1-4 Delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set ecg=%%l%%j%%k
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an easy way is to add the following line

```
echo.ecg=%ecg%
```

By way of explanation...
%%i would be the first token (day of week) which you are not using
%%j is the 2nd token (month)
%%k is the 3rd token (day of month)
%%l is the 4th token (year)
So ecg will contain something like 20130612... depending on the date format your PC is set to use.

Comment: I ran the batch file, but it exits before I can see the output. How do I prevent the command line from closing ?

Comment: Add a PAUSE on the line after the echo

Comment: can you tell me more about how this code works ? like how does the for loop work for this case and what is the purpose of /f,  tokens1-4, delims ? (I know that delimiters are separators). But what do they do in the problem  ?

Comment: I typed for / into my cmd, but i did not see any help for it.

Comment: doing date /t will give you DayofWeek Month/Day/Year (on your PC).  Date format varies by country.  So then when you specify that the / and a space are delimiters, the 1st token is the DayOfWeek; 2nd token is Month; 3rd token is Day; and 4th token is Year.

Answer (score 0):

To get a timestamp: Wmic creates a robust version that doesn't depend on the PC settings, like %date% and date /t do.  Win XP Pro and above.

```
:: time and date stamp YYYYMMDD, HHMMSS and YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set datestamp=%dt:~0,8%
set timestamp=%dt:~8,6%
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set stamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%
echo stamp: "%stamp%"
echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"

pause
```